# Unable to boot with new Nvidia graphics card

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

I recently purchased a Nvidia GT740 graphics card. It worked well for the first 3 hours or so until I needed to reboot. I get the BIOS splash screen and the GRUB splash screen and then freezes. I can choose recovery and perform a `fsck` and then I can get back to the normal boot routine most of the time.

After data mining, I read about the `nomodeset` fix. I tried it, but the problem is not being able to save the changes to the file. Hitting `e` and editing the file doesn't save the changes. I went into the `/etc/default/grub` file and saved the edits, but I don't see them in edit mode grub on boot up.

I purged all the Nvidia files. When it comes to Linux, I'm no expert, but not a novice either. If someone could point me in a direction, it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the line in `/etc/default/grub` is:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

**After making any edits to your grub settings at `/etc/default/grub`, you must run `sudo update-grub`** from a terminal (as you are instructed to do in the developer comments at the top of the file.)

Do that, then reboot, and that line you edited should be loaded into the default boot settings (check using the `e` command as you mentioned previously).

Hope this helps! :)